# Display Date field in email body with rules module

Tags: 7, entities, rules, datetime

On [this page](http://www.bo-medical.com/nl/events/stylage-24nov) I have a ***registration form***. The ***registration form*** is send to an e-mail address with [Rules module.](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)

The related event (Content type 'Event') has a Date field (Wanneer/When), the Date of the event.

How do I display the Date field in the e-mail body? When I put `[entity-fetched:field-event-date]` in the e-mail body, it's not displaying any Date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had a wrong date field. It should be `entity-fetched:field_event_date`. Now its working.